# Pause csharp windows form application from Android phone

Tags: c#, android, windows

A bit of a random question: I have a csharp windows forms application that I would like to pause from my phone. It should be relatively easy to implement and easy to use on my phone.

I have already implemented the pause functionality and can do it pressing the pause button on my pc, but would also like the ability to to do it from my phone.

Things I have considered:
Twilio. This will be perfect as I already send myself watsap message when it starts/finishes. Receiving messages seems to be much more complicated and might be beyond my technical ability. There also doesn't seem to be a way to read the message (but I might have missed it)

Email: I can possibly hook into my Gmail and send myself an email when I want to pause/start it. This looks relatively straightforward to implement in c#. I can then use tasker or something similar to create a widget on my screen that I can press to send myself an email (this sounds easy but I'm still struggling to find an app that can do it)

Has anyone ever tried this before? (It seems like a fairly obvious thing to do but I have had little luck asking Google). Any other recommendations?

Comment: Will it be in the same subnet (WiFi for example) or also from Internet?

Comment: Assuming it can be done from anywhere, you could try firebase.
Its fairly easy to implement on both and fast.

Comment: From anywhere, I guess a Cloud-Based App should be feasable, from same net , only I'd go for a custom UDP-based protocol.

Comment: Yes, I would prefer to do it from anywhere and not just our WiFi. I'll take a look at firebase, thanks Ivan!

Comment: Actually, another thought: I considered writing an API that I could host on Azure. I actually half implemented it before realising that couldn't interact with my pc. But it can... I can write to a storage account that I can access from my pc. I can also create another API to get the value for me. All of these things seem seems rather convulated though. I was hoping there would be a simple way